# how to add a child item to an targetItem which belongs to another tree in aciTree

Tags: jquery, acitree

I want to add an item to targetItem(which belongs to another tree) in an aciTree as shown below :

```
//item is anode to add on targetItem node in a tree
treeApi.append(targetItem, {
                        success: function(targetItem, options) {
                            alert("success");                           
                        },
                        fail: function(targetItem, options) {
                            alert('failed');
                        },
                        itemData:item
           })
```

When i run this code success callback function is called, but the *item* is not appended to *targetItem* and *undefined* is appended.
What could be the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the *append* function does not work for appending an *item* to  *targetItem* which belongs to another tree. Therefore I came up with a solution after trying many things. Below is how I solve the problem :-

```
var treeApi = $('#tree1').aciTree('api');
    treeApi.asChild(item,{
        success: function (item, options){
            //alert(" as child success");
            },
        fail: function (item, options){
            //alert("as child fail");
            var last = treeApi.last (targetItem, true);
            treeApi.moveAfter (item, {
                success: function (item, options){
                    //alert("move after success");
                },
                fail: function (item, options){
                    //alert("move after fail");
                },
                after:last
            });
        },
        parent: targetItem
    });
```